# Controlar cintas RGB led mediante una aplicación de c#

Tags: c#, rgba

Quería saber si alguno ha conectado alguna vez una cinta de luces rgb led con una interfaz de c# , tengo entendido que con arduino se puede controlar un solo led , pero no se si sea posible conectar toda la cinta , para ordenarle encenderla desde el pc. ¿Habria necesidad de conectarla a un raspberry pi?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

Para trabajar con arduino y C# puedes trabajar en Windows Forms con la clase:

[Serial Port](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)

Y en UWP con:

[Windows.Devices.SerialCommunication](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.serialcommunication?view=winrt-19041)

Para encender toda la tira de led lo que necesitaras seguramente es una fuente de alimentación externa y conectarla a un relé junto con tu arduino que sea el que excite el relé. Pregunta en foros más específicos para que resuelvan tus dudas acerca de esto.

La raspberry no te haría falta para nada a no ser que decidas trabajar con Arduino directamente mediante una aplicación UWP en Windows IoT o desde un sistema operativo Linux.